# "System problem detected" message is shown everytime I boot Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu 14.04 in my Lenovo Ideapad S110 netbook (Intel Atom 1.6 GHz, 2 GB RAM). Everytime I log into it, it shows the message "System problem detected". How do I solve this permanently?

Comment: Can you give a bit more info where the error is displayed (log file, on-screen, ...) and provide the relevant output (screenshot, log-file, ...)

Answer (score 17):

The *apport system* creates crash report files in the `/var/crash` directory. These crash report files cause the error message to appear everytime Ubuntu boots.
To get rid of this error messages on bootup type in the terminal `sudo rm /var/crash/*`. It will delete crash report files and this message should stop appearing.

Also follow this [link](http://www.binarytides.com/ubuntu-fix-system-program-problem-error/) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have deleted the crash report files. I guess the problem was related with Google Chrome, because the reports started appearing after I installed it. I have removed Chrome and deleted the crash reports, let's see if any more reports come.